# How to read File Objects out of a jar

Tags: java, jar, java-io, imageicon, zip

I have a jar file that contains a folder structure ie...

jar/com/foo/bar/images

Inside the Images directory I have several images. I have tried to read them out with getResourceAsStream() and also attempted to get at them via ZipEntries.

All of my attempts have been fruitless, if someone could please give me an example on how this would be done.

P.S don't worry about closing resources and error handling etc. I will be able to put that part in.

Thanks for the help.

here is the zipfile entry code I tried

```
private File[] getFilesFromPath(String location) {
        File[] files = null;
        try {
            CodeSource src = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
            if (src != null) {
                URL jar = src.getLocation();
                ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
                while(true) {
                    ZipEntry e = zip.getNextEntry();
                    if (e == null)
                        break;
                    String name = e.getName();
                    if (name.endsWith(location)) {
                         files = new File(name).listFiles((new FileFilter() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean accept(File f) {
                                return f.isFile();
                            }
                        }));
                         for (File file : files){
                             System.out.println(file.getName());
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return files;
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a) the code your already have, b) what the exact "fuitless" error message (or sort of) is.

Comment: Did you try writing the code to unzip the jar file(using java -jar command) into some temp folder and read the images?

Comment: `File` is for individual files stored in the filesystem. You won't be able to construct a `File` which directly references a file within a jar or zipfile.

Comment: The error I am having is that it does indeed not see anything once I construct the File object and try listFiles().

Is there any way to achieve what I am doing or is this unfortunately one of those things where I will have to extract all the files to a temp dir and read them in from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work in your case as I already used following code to read hbm files from an existing jar to create dynamic session factory. It is simply reading the jar file and yhen looking image folder for given location(com/foo/bar/images) then it assume that all the file in this folder are image file. It convert file to Input stream.

Change the JARCLASSNAME to the one of your class name from jar file.

```
CodeSource src = JARCLASSNAME.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
            if (src != null) {
              URL jar = src.getLocation();
              ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
              while(true) {
                ZipEntry e = zip.getNextEntry();
                if (e == null)
                  break;
                String name = e.getName();
                // Check the folder name if folder name match then only read the file
                if (name.startsWith("com/foo/bar/images")) {

                    InputStream inputStream =JARCLASSNAME.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);


              }
            } 
            }
```

Comment: Thanks this is the closest solution to what I need but still not quite there. It looks like I will have to extract the files and then read them in from there.

The problem is that I need to return a File[] as per the interface that I am trying to implement and the only context given to me is the name of the Folder within the jar that I need to get all files from. They are not always going to be Images.

Answer (score 0):

How about constructin a URL image?

```
URL imageURL = JARFILENAME.class.getResource.("pic1.gif");
```

then make the image like this:

```
Image yourImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolKit().getImage(imageURL);
```

URL: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/21906/accessing-images-in-jar-file